# Firebase - Data use

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app where multiple users are sending small messages around in real-time. In order to keep cost down I am going out of my way to make sure only the absolutely essential data is send. The message payload is around 62 bytes (The entire JSON object when looked at as a string)

The message frequency is between 5 and 20 seconds but 24 hours a day by an estimated 100 users. That all adds up but doable.

However, I notice on the Firebase dashboard that the Data usage meter is going up about 3 times faster than it should.

Looking further at the Snapshot object that I receive on a value change and I realize there a lot of extra data that comes along.

So my question: Does anyone know how economic Firebase is in terms of data consumption? Is there anything I can do to minimize the overhead. It seems silly to shave a few bytes off my payload while all this unwieldy unused stuff rides along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

For the Firebase Database we count the traffic at the HTTP protocol level.

There is overhead for setting up the connection between the devices and the servers.

Then there is overhead on each message for things like the path, an acknowledgement or error, and the overhead for the web socket frames.

And depending on how you manage the connections, there will be a cost for keep-alive messages.

Whether those add up to the 3x that you see is hard to say without seeing a [minimal complete example that reproduces the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).